# Google Sheets/Script OnEdit to Change Two Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I've been trying to make a script for a workout calendar.  The idea is to have two versions on separate tabs; one is a list of the days/dates and the workout, and the second is a traditional calendar view.

The challenge I'm running into is the option to extend the calendar, un-hiding hidden rows if a checkbox is selected.  For the "schedule" view, I've been able to get it to work, but I can't get it to work on the separate sheet for the calendar view.  I'd like the one onEdit action to change both sheets, if possible.

This is where I am currently:
The checkbox in H2 on the Schedule Tab is the trigger.  If unchecked, rows 97-124 are hidden, and shown if the box is checked.  The successful code is below, based on what I've modified from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54914048/google-sheets-hiding-rows-based-on-cell-value-yes-no).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() !== 'Schedule') return; 
  if (e.range.getColumn() !== 8) return;
  if (e.value == 'TRUE') {
    switch (e.range.getRow()) {
      case 2:
        sheet.showRows(97,28);
        break;
    }
  } else {
    switch (e.range.getRow()) {
      case 2:
        sheet.hideRows(97,28);
        break;
    }
  }
};
```

But I can't get it to affect the second Calendar sheet.  The default there would be having three months visible, then showing hidden rows for an additional 1-2 months based on how the dates fall.  There's a formula in cell C1 that reflects the number of months (Row 1 would ultimately be hidden), but I haven't been able to find a way to get the code to trigger on the result of the formula.  Using code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58084833/google-spreadsheet-hide-and-unhide-rows-based-on-cell-values), I've been able to get the desired result by manually entering the number of months I want shown, but that's the extra step I'm trying to avoid.  (I know I could make this a little easier to manage by moving the hidden rows calculated dates to the top of the sheet, for a more concise showRows/hideRows; the layout was done before I decided to try this automating the sheet).

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if( activeSheet.getName() == 'Calendar' ) {
    var activeRange = ss.getActiveRange();
    var activeRow = activeRange.getRow();
    var activeColumn = activeRange.getColumn()
    if( activeColumn == 3 && activeRow == 1 ) {
      if ( activeRange.getValue() == '3' )
        activeSheet.hideRows(65,42);
      if ( activeRange.getValue() == '4' )
        activeSheet.showRows(65,21);
        activeSheet.hideRows(66,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(69,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(72,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(75,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(78,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(81,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(84,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(86,21);
      if ( activeRange.getValue() == '5' )
        activeSheet.showRows(65,42);
        activeSheet.hideRows(66,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(69,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(72,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(75,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(78,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(81,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(84,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(87,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(90,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(93,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(96,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(99,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(102,1);
        activeSheet.hideRows(105,1);
    }
  }
};
```

Any help, even confirmation that an onEdit can't affect multiple sheets, would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`onEdit` simple trigger can affect multiple sheets it has several limitations including an execution time limit of 30 secs. Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

As `hideRows` is a slow operation and you script have a several of them perhaps the solution is to used a installable trigger instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input; I think I may go back and rework it all as conditional formatting, with the hidden rows blacked out.